# How to fade whole screen

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am presenting a temporary view on top of my view controller when a user does some action.

I want it to fade the screen - including the navigation bar, like [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does. 
I am presenting the view via the root view controller of the navigation controller, so my only problem is **to fade also the navigation bar and not allow touches on it**.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a semi-transparent view on the whole `UIWindow` and it'll look just as you described it. You'd probably want to add your temporary view there, too, because all actions will be blocked by the semi-transparent view.

Comment: Wow, I didn't knew I can add a subview to the uiwindow. thanks a ton.